# Dropzone component

Tags: jquery, upload

I'm trying to work with the Dropzone component for Uploading Files, I can already save my files in the database. The problem that is happening is to reload the existing files in the database, as soon as I load my page. I run into the following error:

> dropzone.min.js: 1 Error not detected: Dropzone already attached

When saved as images in the b.d., instance the Dropzone component, like this:

```
let myDropzone = new Dropzone ("#idDropzone-" + relationshipId, {...}
```

And to rescue the existing images in the database, I am instantiating again, as above, since the common error occurs. There is a way to get the Dropzone id without instantiating it, since it has already been instantiated.

I tried this way, being my id is concatenated, how to define in the definition of the variable.

```
Dropzone.options.idDropzone {}
```

Dropzone id definition:

```
  <div class="dropzone" id="dzUpload-@Model.IdRelacionamento"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to instantiate DZ again? Your variable `myDropzone` allows you to access every part of DZ. I would create another div who display already attached images.

Comment: Or you could use your var `myDropzone` to dynamically add images already attached. But that will be more complex I think